# CSS - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-devtools, github-pages, safari-web-inspector

I am trying to load my simple website online hosted by Github.io. However, after countless and frustrating efforts of troubleshooting and debugging the HTML & CSS script, my web still couldn't get the CSS file loaded as desired for some really mysterious and extremely annoying reason.

Don't get me wrong:

1. I swear my CSS file is put in the absolute path rather than the relative path as I firstly put it, so I will smash myself if it's the cause of the error.
2. After a while couldn't figure out, I looked over similar or related issues posted on stackoverflow as well, some suggest that the access permission is maybe the reason, but I followed them with the command inside my directory of CSS file

> chmod -R 777

But I don't see it resolves as well cuz the command has no effect, and I didn't run it at the root level
[image: the file is not at the root level]

3. I inspected this web on both Chrome and Safari, and the *style.css* is blank as it couldn't be loaded!!! [image]

Now, I keep hold on this to wait for any of your "magic" helps. I deeply appreciate the help, as I tried my best fixing it already, but didnt work.
Here is the just HTML link tag line where the file is not loaded.

```
<head>
....

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./_css/style.css">
</head>
```

Comment: Don't think there's any way we could help with just this information and screenshots. Can you provide links to your HTML and CSS file?

Comment: It just occurred to me that my answer is probably based off of it not working in Chrome/Safari, instead of its actual file structure on its host. If so, I'll update my answer to something more useful when more information is published

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `_css` directory is in the root, your CSS link should start with a slash:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/_css/style.css">
```

But naming your directory `_css` may be a problem. [Github Pages](https://help.github.com/articles/about-github-pages-and-jekyll/) by default treats your site as a [Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/) website, which processes your files and **[does not publish files/directories having `_` prefix.](https://help.github.com/articles/files-that-start-with-an-underscore-are-missing/)**

I think you have 2 options:

- If you don't know about Jekyll and you are not creating a Jekyll site, put a file in your root named `.nojekyll` to [bypass Jekyll processing](https://github.com/blog/572-bypassing-jekyll-on-github-pages).
- Rename your directory from `_css` to `css` and also modify your `<link>` tag.

Comment: Yes, I haven't touched Jekyll seriously. Let me try this. Thank @juzraai

Comment: You're the savior of the day!!!! Not just of that fix, but I learned crucial things from your explanation. The trick to bypass Jekyll processing is so nifty!

Comment: You're welcome, glad to help! :) Also a side note: I highly recommend you to get familiar with Jekyll, it can help a lot in creating static websites. :)